# Response to FHIR ServiceRequest

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm new to FHIR and need to support a scenario where a provider broadcasts a required need for services to other providers. We'll be using R4 so sending a ServiceRequest to each potential performer seems reasonable, but it's not clear how the potential performers should accept or revoke the service request.

Any insight appreciated!
Scott C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServiceRequest represents an authorization.  By itself, it doesn't ask anyone to act on it.  To solicit fulfillment of the ServiceRequest, you need to use one of the mechanisms defined in the FHIR [workflow section](https://build.fhir.org/workflow-communications.html).  Most of these approaches make use of 'Task', which allows for explicit acceptance or refusal of the request to fulfill (as well as updates on progress and eventual attachment of the results).

Note also that the refusal of one provider to fulfill the order doesn't change the status of the ServiceRequest - it still remains an active authorization.  It's possible to send a second Task seeking fulfillment, or even a third until someone agrees to perform it - and actually delivers as promised.